# A variable in a for loop is changing without being supposed to change in c

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, cs50, undefined-behavior

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf
#include <cs50.h> // get_long
#include <string.h> // strlen
#include <stdlib.h> // stdlib

int credit_test(string input);

int main(void)
{
    string userInput;

    // Gets user input, and tests if input is valid
    bool isInvalid = false;
    do
    {
        userInput = get_string("Number: "); // Prompts user for input

        for(int i = 0, evenIndex = strlen(userInput); evenIndex > i; i++)
        {
            if(userInput[i] - 48 >= 0 && userInput[i] - 48 <= 9 && (strlen(userInput) == 15 || strlen(userInput) == 16)) // Tests if input is valod
            {
                isInvalid = false;
            }
            else
            {
                isInvalid = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while(isInvalid);

    int keyValidity = credit_test(userInput);
}

int credit_test(string input)
{
    int inputLen;
    inputLen = strlen(input);

    // Even number calculation

    int evenArr[16];

    int evenSum = 0;

    int evenIndex = 0;

    printf("Length: %i\n", inputLen);

    for(int i = 0; inputLen > i; i++)
    {
        int n = i * 2;

        evenArr[evenIndex] = input[n] * 2;

        if(evenArr[evenIndex] > 0)
        {
            evenArr[evenIndex] -= 96;
        }

        if(evenArr[evenIndex] > 9) // Code to split doubles
        {
            int doubleNum = evenArr[evenIndex];

            evenArr[evenIndex] = 1;

            evenIndex++;

            evenArr[evenIndex] = doubleNum % 10;
        }

        evenIndex++;

        evenSum += evenArr[i];

        printf("%i\n", evenArr[i]);
        printf("Length: %i\n", inputLen);
    }

    printf("Length: %i\n", inputLen);

    printf("Even Sum: %i\n", evenSum);

    // Odd number calculation

    int oddArr[16];

    int oddSum = 0;

    int oddIndex = 1;


    for(int i = 0; 16 > i; i++)
    {
        oddArr[i] = input[oddIndex];

        if(oddArr[i] > 0)
        {
            oddArr[i] -= 48;
        }

        oddSum += oddArr[i];

        oddIndex += 2;

        printf("%i\n", oddArr[i]);
    }

    printf("Odd Sum: %i\n", oddSum);

    // Validity test

    int finalSum = evenSum + oddSum;

    int cardType = finalSum % 10;

    printf("Final Sum: %i\n", finalSum);



    if(cardType == 0 && (input[0] - 48) == 5)
    {
        printf("MasterCard \n");
    }else if (cardType == 0 && (input[0] - 48) == 4)
    {
        printf("Visa \n");
    }else if(cardType == 0 && (input[0] - 48) == 3)
    {
        printf("Amex \n");
    }else
    {
        printf("Invalid \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I just cannot wrap my head around why, but if you run the code, and keep an eye on the "inputLen" variable it stays what it should be, but in the first for loop which gets the even number in the input, the inputLen stays the same, which is correct, but when the loop finishes, for some reason, the variable changes to 0? So would anyone mind to explain as to why its happening? And sorry if the code is all wonky and bad :)

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the loop

```
for(int i = 0; inputLen > i; i++)
{
    int n = i * 2;

    evenArr[evenIndex] = input[n] * 2;

    //...
```

invokes undefined behavior because the expression input[n]  can access memory beyond the used array due to using the expression `i * 2` as an index. For example then i is equal to `inputLen - 1` then n will bi initialized by the expression `2 * ( inputLen - 1 )` and the value of the expression you are using as an index to access elements of the array `input` but the array does not have so many elements.

Also in this code snippet

```
    if(evenArr[evenIndex] > 9) // Code to split doubles
    {
        int doubleNum = evenArr[evenIndex];

        evenArr[evenIndex] = 1;

        evenIndex++;

        evenArr[evenIndex] = doubleNum % 10;
    }

    evenIndex++;
```

the variable `evenIndex` can be incremented twice that again can be a reason of undefined behavior when this variable is used as an index to access elements of the array `evenArr`.

Comment: Hmm, would you mind explaining what that means in more simpler terms? I apologize for my stupidity, I'm just quite new to the whole new cs concept, and some of the terminology just pass over my head. Thank you so much for your help though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @IncognitoSpeedy For example if you  have an array a[] with one element and initially its index i is equal to 0 then using this code int j = i; ++j; ++j; a[j] = 10; will invoke undefined behavior because the expression a[j] that represents the expression a[j] is trying to access memory beyond the allocated array.

Comment: @IncognitoSpeedy That is you are using indices that are outside valid ranges of indices for your arrays,

Comment: I see, so essentially, in the a[j] = 10 snippet, its changing the value of the j?

Comment: And presumably would you mind enlightening me on possible fixes, or what I can do to go about fixing it?

Comment: @IncognitoSpeedy It changes the memory beyond the array a that has only one element. So the valid range for indices for this array is [0, 1). As a result any variable that is stored in the memory after the array will be changed.